# Can't get if else to work right in HAML javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

Doing a little demo mini-blog app with comments. Working with ROR and HAML. I want the comments to be created with AJAX so I wrote create.js.haml. I also want errors to appear if there were any during the creation.

**create.js.haml**

```
:plain
if #{@comment.errors.any?} {
  $("#CommentError").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "error"))}");
  $("#CommentError").attr("style", "display: inline");
} else {
  $("#CommentsTable").append("#{escape_javascript(render(@comment))}");
  $("#CommentError").attr("style", "display: false");}
```

This doesn't work. The condition evaluates to either `true` or `false` but the code is not executed. But if I put any part of the condition on it's own in the create.js.haml it works.

This works in case there's an error:

```
:plain
  $("#CommentError").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "error"))}");
  $("#CommentError").attr("style", "display: inline");
```

This works in case there's no error and I need to add the comment:

```
:plain
  $("#CommentsTable").append("#{escape_javascript(render(@comment))}");
  $("#CommentError").attr("style", "display: false");
```

this is the view, though I don't think the problem is there:

```
%p
  %strong Title:
  = @post.title

%p
  %strong Text:
  = @post.text

%h3 Comments:
.CommentsArea
  = render @post.comments

#CommentError{:style => 'display: none'}  

%h2 Add a comment:
= render "comments/form"

= link_to 'Back', posts_path
|
= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post)
```

Comment: Ruby, javascript, AND HAML? That's an awful lot of mixing for a JS file... Have you tested create.js.erb and does it work there?

Comment: Anything you can do with erb you can do with HAML and vice versa. This isn't production code, just an exercise, trying to learn this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe this will work ( I can't check it now myself)

```
- if @comment.errors.any?
  :plain
    $("#CommentError").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "error"))}");
    $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "true");
- else
  :plain
    $("#CommentsTable").append("#{escape_javascript(render(@comment))}");
    $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "false");
```

Comment: Doesn't work. By looking at the broswer dev tool network data it send this:

`if @comment.errors.any?
  $("#CommentError").html("<h2>\n  1 error\n  prohibited this comment from being saved\n<\/h2>\n<ul>\n  <li>\n    Commenter is too short (minimum is 5 characters)\n  <\/li>\n<\/ul>\n");
  $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "true");
else`
...etc

Comment: oh my fault - I missed `-` to say HAML that this is ruby code. Try updated variant

Comment: Thanks, it worked, just had to fix the indents and move the `:plain` filter inside the `- if` and `- else`

Comment: And wrap this all in `%script{type: "text/javascript"}`, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing Ruby and Javascript a bit too much here.  Try this instead.

```
if @comment.errors.any?
  :javascript
    $("#CommentError").html("#{escape_javascript(render(:partial => "error"))}");
    $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "true");
else
  :javascript
    $("#CommentsTable").append("#{escape_javascript(render(@comment))}");
    $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "false");
```

For more documentation: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter

Comment: Nope. Got an indentation error at first, then unindented the :javascript filters and what's under them, and then it just generates the partial class and sends:

`if @comment.errors.any?
<script>
  $("#CommentError").html("<h2>\n  1 error\n  prohibited this comment from being saved\n<\/h2>\n<ul>\n  <li>\n    Commenter is too short (minimum is 5 characters)\n  <\/li>\n<\/ul>\n");
  $("#CommentError").attr("visible", "true");
</script>
<script>
  $("#CommentsTable").append("<div class=\'comment\' `

etc...